# how to change max_input_vars value on godaddy server

Tags: php

How to change max_input_vars value on godaddy server. i have tried using all possible way. changing in php.ini file,  htaccess file wp-config etc. but still issue is not resolved

Comment: Use a .user.ini file

Answer (score 6):

**Solution 1:** Using server

PHP obtains input variables from HTML forms (through GET and POST requests), as well as from any cookies enabled on a page. By default, the maximum number of input variables allowed for PHP scripts is set to 1000.

You are advised to change this amount by setting the max_input_vars directive in a php.ini file.

While working on a website hosted on GoDaddy shared hosting package, adding it to php.ini doesn’t work. What works for me is to add this in the .user.ini file at the www root folder, i.e., public_html. Yes, you read it correctly, it is “.user.ini“. The line is simple:

> max_input_vars = 3000

This increases the value from 1000 to 3000.

**Solution 2:** Using .htaccess

One piece of advice is to add the following code in the .htaccess file

```
php_value max_input_vars 1000
php_value suhosin.get.max_vars 1000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 1000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 1000
```

Comment: .user.ini works!  it takes a couple minutes after creating the file.

Comment: I created the .user.ini file in my computer and uploaded it with the cPanel File Admin, and it worked, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

There is an option existed in whm panel to do this. If you have already purchased whm panel, You can apply the value via "php configuration editor"

[image]